# Regex to replace a part of string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like

```
 "target:40,trg: tra:20,this:30"
```

I want to replace **trg:** 
or in other words, anything before colon followed by one empty space should be replaced.

I don't have any easy way to do it.
Any help will be great.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you found any similar questions/answers?

Comment: so wrong to give -1 withoput even understanding the question and not having breath of what someone is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your desired output, but you can try:

```
import re
s = "target:40,trg: tra:20,this:30"
print re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+:\s', ' ', s)
```

output:

```
target:40, tra:20,this:30
```

If you want to just delete it without adding a space, use `''` instead of `' '`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newb and not sure about this question. But from what I understand I would do this.

```
import re
text = "target:40,trg: tra:20,this:30"
findText = re.compile(r": ")
mo = ft.search(text)
mog = mo.group()
textsplit = re.split((mog), text)[1]
print(textsplit)
```

which will output:

```
tra:20,this:30
```